# Setting Makefile variable to result of command in rule

Tags: git, makefile

I am trying to assign the result of a command to a variable in GNU make.  It works if I do it outside the rule:

```
$ cat stack.mk
GIT_BRANCH=$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

all:
    @echo Git branch is $(GIT_BRANCH)

$ make -f stack.mk all
Git branch is dev
```

But not if I put it in the rule body:

```
$ cat stack.mk
all:
    export GIT_BRANCH=$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
    @echo Git branch is $(GIT_BRANCH)

$ make -f stack.mk all
export GIT_BRANCH=dev
Git branch is
```

Is it possible to assign variables in a rule.  At this point I would like to assign the results of a couple of `git` commands to shell/`Makefile` variables.

Comment: I just updated my answer. I misinterpreted your question earlier to mean that you were trying to set a shell variable.

Comment: The command lines are run in separate shells; the second line doesn't know about the environment variable set in the first.  Options include using a semicolon and backslash at the end of the first line (and drop the `@` at the beginning of the second.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, if you are trying to set a `Makefile` variable, you can do it using [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) function.

```
all:
    $(eval GIT_BRANCH=$(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD))
    echo Git branch is $(GIT_BRANCH)
```